# Binding property, but no change code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, properties, code-behind

I have an UserControl with an FontFamily property (is inherited from Control Class wich is Bindable property).

In an Second Class inherited from Adorner i try to bind to the FontFamily (and some other Fontstuff) to my DependencyStuff to recive the actual FontStuff.

Here some Code:

```
public class CaretAndMarker : System.Windows.Documents.Adorner
{

   public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FontFamily", typeof(FontFamily), typeof(CaretAndMarker), new PropertyMetadata(new FontFamily("Arial")));

   public System.Windows.Media.FontFamily FontFamily
   {
        get { return (System.Windows.Media.FontFamily)this.GetValue(FontFamilyProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value); }
    }

   /// <summary>
   /// Binds an Property of Anchestor to this
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="dp">this DependencyProperty</param>
   /// <param name="Path">Anchestor Path</param>
   /// <param name="typ">Type of Anchestor</param>
   private void bind(DependencyProperty dp, string Path, Type typ)
   {
       //Binding
       Binding BFS = new Binding();
       BFS.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typ, 1);
       BFS.Path = new PropertyPath(Path);
       var bes = this.SetBinding(dp, BFS);
   }


   public CaretAndMarker(System.Windows.UIElement adornedElement)
       : base(adornedElement)
   {

       //Binding FontFamily
       bind(FontFamilyProperty, "FontFamily", typeof(txtField));

    ....
```

But the Binding seems not working.
If i change the FontFamily in my UserControl, the FontFamily at CaretAndMarker Class will not be Updated.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: TextBlock.SetFontFamily(....)

Comment: it's an attachedproperty 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.setfontfamily(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Ok, seems only not working in CreationContext, after returning of it, its seems working now, thx a lot